# Is it possible to use Infinispan as a blocking cache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, infinispan, spring-cache

In our project we are using Infinispan and Spring's `@Cacheable` annotation, mainly for caching I/O results.

As we have many concurrent calls, we would like to avoid 2 threads performing the same data retrieval twice, hence having the second `@Cacheable` method call (with the same cache key) blocked until the first one finishes and returns a result.

I am used to Ehcache's [`SelfPopulatingCache`](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.6.9/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/SelfPopulatingCache.html) which supports this automatically, but is there a similar feature in Infinispan?

Ideally this should be used via Spring's `@Cacheable` so that we avoid boilerplate code. I have noticed that Spring 4.3 now has [`@Cacheable.sync()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#sync--) but it is indicated that it is only a hint and it depends on the underlying cache provider implementation. Also, we are not on Spring 4.3 yet so a solution for 4.2 would be better.

Comment: Spring's JCache adapters proxy to call the [invoke method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/jcache/JCacheCache.java#L80) for the `sync` feature. So support seems likely or perhaps you can call it directly.

Comment: @BenManes `JCacheCache` only delegates to the underlying `JCache`, but that does not make it automatically blocking, right?

Comment: `invoke` is supposed to be atomic, so it could block when waiting for its turn. In effect it should act like a `sync(key)` rather than a lock-free read when present, because JCache doesn't allow that unless using a loader.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that feature out-of-the-box you'll have to upgrade to 4.3. If you are using 4.2, upgrading to 4.3 should be painless anyway (if that's not the case, let us know!)

As Ben already mentioned, you can use the JCache bridge that has explicit support for such a call (i.e. it will work for any JSR-107 compliant cache library). Infinispan does not have such native feature yet, I've just [submitted a feature request in their tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7224).